# rmi eclipse UnmarshalException ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

So I'm trying to use rmi with packages in eclipse and it doesn't seem to work.

this is ServeurImpl.java which extends Serveur.java both located in the bin/Server/ folder

```
try
{
    ServeurImpl serv = new ServeurImpl(Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
        Integer.parseInt(args[2]),
        Integer.parseInt(args[3]),
        Integer.parseInt(args[4]),
        Integer.parseInt(args[5]));
    Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:"+ args[0] + "/Serveur", serv);
    System.out.println("Serveur en service");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("ServeurImpl : " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried to use the codename option without success.
So how can I make java understand what I want ?

And I can't seem to get rmic working it also tells me that there isn't any Server.ServerImpl in my class, I know it's deprecated but

```
if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
    System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
```

doesn't change anything !

P.S. : I'm on Windows

**EDIT** : stacktrace

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Server.Serveur
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:420)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1875819480.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Unknown Source)
at Server.ServeurImpl.main(ServeurImpl.java:240)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Server.Serveur
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:410)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1875819480.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Server.Serveur
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler$Loader.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:1207)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClassForName(LoaderHandler.java:1221)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(LoaderHandler.java:731)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:674)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:611)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:646)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:311)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:255)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1559)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
... 16 more
```

**EDIT 2** : Flagging my post isn't helping me ... I already looked into the post linked, but it didn't help me.

I got it working but without eclipse,
I did it like that :

```
javac Server\*.java in my src\ folder
start rmiregistry 5000
java Server.ServeurImpl <parameters>
```

but that's a really ugly way to do it ...

Comment: Can you add some more information, like a stacktrace indicating what class it's saying is not found and what line is causing the problem?

Comment: I added the stacktrace, the problem is located on the 240th line which corresponds to the `Naming.rebind`